# Json ajax call returning response 200 ok

Tags: ajax

Here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value= "call web service" onclick="callwebservice()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert('call stastus:' + result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
            alert('responsetest"'+result.responseText);
            alert('errorthrown' + result.errorThrown);

        }
        function callwebservice() {
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "default.aspx/LoginFromFacebook",
                        data: "",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                        },
                        error: AjaxFailed
                    }
                   );
        }
</script>

code behind -----------------

[WebMethod()]
    public static string LoginFromFacebook()
    {
        return "helloworld";
    }
```

---

This is very simple code I have only one web method in my default.aspx file  when i am calling the webmethod  I am getting response code 200 ok.
I investigated using fiddler 
response is as below
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
   X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2011 09:16:21 GMT
  Content-Length: 1535

don't know why this is happening. I am expecting only string as response where i am getting whole page's html  as response.

Comment: Have you had a look at the response sent back by the server.  Is it hello world?  You can use firebug to check it.

Comment: If you return {"text":"helloworld"}? Have you tried?

Comment: No I am not getting  hello world in response.Instead of that I am getting html of  default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with web site and web applications in visual studio. you can just put the design code in your aspx file or just use web-service instead of the default.aspx.
following link containing basic steps for success ajax request using jQuery, JavaScript or asp.net ajax,

[sample site for basic ajax function](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-call-csharp-function-in-ajax.html)

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly with web service call. But I have to access httpcontext /session object  in the web method which is not possible if i will go with webservice that's why I used pagemethod            Any other alternative?

Comment: you can use session in web-service. see [MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.session.aspx) for how to do it

Comment: Thanks Chamika above solution worked.  Apart from above solution by find another alternative solution at [This link](http://www.chadscharf.com/index.php/2009/11/creating-a-page-method-scriptmethod-within-an-ascx-user-control-using-ajax-json-base-classes-and-reflection/)