# How to get Ajax response in HTML Unit (it renders the HTML of the web page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, testing, htmlunit

I have a web application that returns JSON when I make AJAX requests to the server for CRUD operations. The reason of this is because I use jQuery to handle the data without refreshing the page (MVC), so if I create a new entry in the system, the server will return a response which have the created entry in JSON format. jQuery manages the data received and renders the entry on a list (with the previously created entries).

Now I am testing it with HTML Unit, but if I try

```
WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse()
```

I get 200 status and message "OK". But I was expecting the JSON data of the entry I created.

And if I try

```
page.asText()
```

I get the HTML of the current page (with the entry already in the list, but not the data I want).

It is a similar issue than this one, that had no response: [Json ajax call returning response 200 ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063560/json-ajax-call-returning-response-200-ok)

PD: The jQuery form has two fields, one is a text input for the name and another is a select for the car settings. I pass to this function a list of settings to select. The name is autogenerated with a timestamp and a static int seed. This is the code that I am using:

```
public void create(List<Settings> settings) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    page = webClient.getPage("localhost:8080/cars/list");

    int elementsCount = getEntitiesCount();
    creationSeed = elementsCount+1;

    HtmlAnchor anchor = (HtmlAnchor) page.getFirstByXPath("//a[@class='action-createCar']");
    page = (HtmlPage) anchor.click();

    HtmlForm form = page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@class='CarsForm']");
    form = page.getForms().get(0);
    HtmlTextInput nameField = form.getInputByName("CarsForm-name");
    nameField.setText("Test " + creationSeed + " - " + new Date().getTime());

    HtmlSelect columnSelectList = (HtmlSelect) form.getSelectByName("CarsForm-settings");
    if (settings != null && settings.size() > 0)
        for (Settings setting : settings)
        {
            HtmlOption htmlOption = columnSelectList.getOptionByValue(setting.name());
            htmlOption.setSelected(true);
        }

    //looking for the button to submit the form
    HtmlDivision buttonSet = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']");
    HtmlButton okButton = (HtmlButton) buttonSet.getFirstElementChild();

    page = okButton.click();

    assertEquals(elementsCount + 1, getEntitiesCount());

    //Here is where I want to get the server response to check the data which is returned by the server
    //And neither page.getWebResponse() or page.asText() contains it
}
```

}

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: "if I try

WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse()

I get 200 status and message "OK". But I was expecting the JSON data of the entry I created.

And if I try

page.asText()

I get the HTML of the current page (with the entry already in the list, but not the data I want)."

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I have included the code of the test case

Comment: Obviously, it is impossible to know what is going on without the HTML code. EG: You said you expected `page` to have the response... but what does `okButton.click()` do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found a solution using the [HtmlUnit FAQ page](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse):

> You can subclass HttpWebConnection and override getResponse() as:
>
> ```
>    new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {
>
>        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
>            WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
>            if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("my_url")) {
>                String content = response.getContentAsString("UTF-8");
>
>                //change content
>
>                WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes("UTF-8"),
>                        response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), >response.getResponseHeaders());
>                response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
>            }
>            return response;
>        }
>    };
> ```

What this means is that we can wrap our webClient object, intercept any request and response we need, extract them or make changes.

---

I made an inner class which extends WebConnectionWrapper, and has one field which is JSON I need:

```
private class JsonResponseWebWrapper extends WebConnectionWrapper{

    public JsonResponseWebWrapper(WebClient webClient){
        super(webClient);           
    }
    
    String jsonResponse;
    
    @Override
    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {;
        WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
        //extract JSON from response
        jsonResponse = response.getContentAsString();
        return response;
    }

    public String getJsonResponse() {
        return jsonResponse;
    }
};
```

This way we will intercept every single response. But first we need to wrap the webClient. I did this just before requesting JSON response, so I didn't have to add conditions to my wrapper:

```
JsonResponseWebWrapper jrww = new JsonResponseWebWrapper(webClient);
page = button.click();
String rawJSON = jrww.getJsonResponse();
```

And after that you can parse it using your favorite JSON parser.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to just let ***JsonResponseWebWrapper extends HttpWebConnection*** and used the JsonResponseWebWrapper by doing ***webClient.setWebConnection(jsonResponseWebWrapper);*** where **jsonResponseWebWrapper = new JsonResponseWebWrapper(webClient);**